# Does the blog comments section support markdown?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting, blog

I made [a comment](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/19/privacy-is-an-afterthought-in-the-software-lifecycle-that-needs-to-change/#comment-2024404) on the [*'Privacy is an afterthought in the software lifecycle. That needs to change.'*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/19/privacy-is-an-afterthought-in-the-software-lifecycle-that-needs-to-change/?cb=1) article and the formatting is very strange.  I can't tell if I messed it up or if it just doesn't support certain features.

Specifically, I *definitely* figured it would support line breaks since the post directly above mine has line breaks.  I also included some **bold** markdown but that didn't get transformed.  The comment is still "awaiting moderation" so maybe it only gets transformed after approval.

Does the blog comments section support any kind of markup?  Can you add a "help" piece detailing what is supported?  If the post is only transformed *after* approval, can that be called out or maybe changed?

Comment: Looks like your comment has been approved and the bold markdown isn't rendered. On the other hand, I don't think it supports any formatting.

Comment: It is [a WordPress blog](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/06/24/formatting-wordpress-comments-e-g-on-the-stack-overflow-official-blog/), completely separate from the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange software/system.